# Web scraping with R, solution with Jsonlite seems flaky

Tags: json, r, web-scraping

I maintain small scrips to extract financial data from websites. One of them retrieves the dutch natural gas grid balance. However, I keep getting problems with it as it works for a while, then get an error message and finally find a work around. Anyway, it seems that I am using a rather flaky method to do it. Could anyone guide me to a better direction (package) of getting this done?
Below I add the code (which again stopped working)

```
library(curl)
library(bitops)  
url <- "https://www.gasunietransportservices.nl/en/shippers/balancing-regime/sbs-and-pos/graphactualjson/MWh"
h <- new_handle(copypostfields ="moo=moomooo")
handle_setheaders(h, "Content-Type" = "text/moo", "Cache-Control" = "no-cache", "User-Agent" = "A cow") 
req <- curl_fetch_memory(url, handle=h)
x <- rawToChar(req$content)
library(jsonlite)
json_data <- fromJSON(x)

data <- json_data[,c(1,4)]
n=tail(data,1)
```

Many thanks

Comment: What are the errors you get? `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.gasunietransportservices.nl/en/shippers/balancing-regime/sbs-and-pos/graphactualjson/MWh")` works perfectly (30 tries)

Comment: should have that added in the first place.. when running json_data <- fromJSON(x) I get: Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!doctype html> <!--[if lte IE 
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: you wouldn't be behind a proxy server (inline or otherwise), perchance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rvest` for this (but there could be better approaches too)

```
library(rvest)

json_data <- read_html('https://www.gasunietransportservices.nl/en/shippers/balancing-regime/sbs-and-pos/graphactualjson/MWh') %>% 
             html_text() %>% 
             jsonlite::fromJSON(.) 

data <- json_data[,c(1,4)]
n=tail(data,1)
n
```

Output:

```
> n
           sbsdatetime position
37 2017-11-16 12:00:00       -9
```

Slightly elegant solution if the dataframe isn't required:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
read_html('https://www.gasunietransportservices.nl/en/shippers/balancing-regime/sbs-and-pos/graphactualjson/MWh') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  jsonlite::fromJSON(.)  %>%
  select(1:4) %>% 
  tail(n=1)
```